# AWS API Gateway with static IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

When you create an API using Gateway and map a custom domain, 
AWS API Gateway makes an entry in cloudfront distribution

source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

> For every API you create, API Gateway sets up an Amazon CloudFront distribution for the API. Requests with the default API URL are routed through the corresponding CloudFront distribution. Similarly, for every custom domain name, API Gateway sets up a CloudFront distribution. An API request with the custom domain name is routed through the custom domain name's CloudFront distribution.

However the cloudfront IPs can change when AWS updates the [ip ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-egress-control).

As a user of the API, how do I bind a static IP to the custom domain mapped to Gateway so that I need not update firewall egress settings whenever AWS updates the IP ranges?

Comment: has somebody tried https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/expose-aws-lambda-function-behind-static-ip-when-a-dns-cannot-be-managed/

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible to attach a static IP to API Gateway. However, AWS Publishes the [IP ranges used by CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html) which can be used to whitelist the firewall egress settings.

Since these IP ranges also can change, it is recommended to automate the checking for changes using [this](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) URL and update the rules accordingly.

Comment: this is a tiresome approach to change the firewall settings by grabbing all cloud front ip ranges (there are 42 entries in json with massive range). But I understand, this is the only option I see now.

Comment: is there any other option other than making changes to the firewall ?

Comment: Is putting CloudFlare in front with a CNAME to API-G an option?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CloudFlare. If it supports proxying to HTTPS endpoints and Header Whitelisting both, my guess is it should work with APG.

Comment: Yes, it does support proxying to HTTPS. We are using it for achieving static ip on APIG, and it works fairly well (un-noticeable overhead).

Comment: @AlbertoDallaporta How do you achieve static IP with CloudFlare? AFAIK CloudFlare has dynamic range, just like CloudFront.

Comment: Good answer, but that AWS ip change adds some really high complexity when we have Openshift egress policy(which has a limit of numbers of rules) and then, our firewall. Both basically works only with IP and needs to request IP to DNS and that constant change causes lead to inconsistency which drops packets.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to multi cloud ;-)

I was researching on this topic and found that there are solutions from other cloud providers.

1. Google GCP : https://cloud.google.com/cdn/

   So google CDN do provide one anycast IP by default.
2. Microsoft Azure API management 
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/
   Do provide static IP.

In my opinion for AWS they solved the static IP problem with global accelerator or NLB but the problem is that both of these products are not layers 7 API management solutions.

So basically at this point , you can solve layer 4 but for layer 7 you need to use api gateway or cloud front and both don't have any direct integration with global accelerator or NLB.

In google solution atleast their CDN give only one anycast IP, which is not yet there in AWS cloudfront ( although matter of time )

I liked Microsoft API management for this particular case , where u get static ip + API management in one solution.

Comment: Just an observation - once deployed, Google Cloud Functions HTTP triggers seem to obtain a static IP (not changing based on access location or on subsequent redeployments)... in fact it looks like all functions in a given GCP project point to the same static IP.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is to have something with a static ip between the client and the api gateway such as a virtual machine whose only goal is to reroute all the calls to the api gateway.

It would literally be like 50 lines of code of bouncing requests and responses, but it adds complexity and budget requirements.